# Program doesn't exit from while block

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a `while` block, and inside it I have decision making blocks including `elif` blocks. I want that the program exits from the while block when `obje_error == 0`, but the while block repeats instead.

I suppose that `obje_error == 0` when the other conditions are not complete. I removed the `elif` blocks and it worked, but I want that the all blocks go to work.

You can see the code below:

```
while (obje_error == 1):    
    Sen=raw_input("tas mi,kagit mi yoksa makas mi?")
    if (Sen != "tas") :
        print "Lutfen tas,kagit ya da makas'i secin..."
        obje_error=1
    elif (Sen != "kagit"):
        print "Lutfen tas,kagit ya da makas'i secin..."
        obje_error=1
    elif Sen != "makas":
        print "Lutfen tas,kagit ya da makas'i secin..."
        obje_error=1
    else:
        obje_error=0
```

Can you tell me what the problem is and what I can do?

Comment: `Sen` can only hold *one* string, so it'll be `tas` or `kagit` or `makas` or something else, so it'll *always* trigger either the first or the second of the three `!=` tests. It'll never get to the last `else` statement. Did you perhaps mean to test for `==` instead?

Comment: What @MartijnPieters said.  I'm thinking you may want `in` tests, or a single `if` with multiple conditions `or`ed together.  Also, if all you want is an infinite loop to break out of when a condition is satisfied, `for` with `break` tends to be cleaner.  Could you lay out your requirements for this whole chunk of code, from a higher level?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I resolved the problem using tuples like this:if Sen in ("tas","kagit","makas") :obje_error=0

Answer (score 1):

If the string is equal to one of the strings you're testing against, it will be unequal to all the others. Thus one of the `if` statements is guaranteed to succeed, and you'll never reach the `else` at the end.

You probably wanted `==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want that when the user-input is unequal to "tas","kagit" or "makas" the while loop must be repeat. Wherefore I write if (Sen != "tas") but when I give the values "tas","kagit" or "makas" from the terminal it's repeating too like other input that are unequal to "tas","kagit" or "makas" and doesn't exit from the while loop.

Comment: @ErenCan, as long as you set `obje_error=1` then the while loop will repeat.